# Boost serialization with pointers and non-default constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

How would you serialize/deserialize this class using boost::serialization?

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    struct Bar {
        std::vector<int> * data; // Must point to Foo::data

        Bar( std::vector<int> * d ) : data(d) { }
    };

    std::vector<int> data;
    std::vector<Bar> elements;

    Foo() {
        // do very time consuming calculation to populate "data" and "elements"
    }
};
```

The constructor in Foo must not be executed when the objected is loaded from the serialized data, but if the object is default constructed the constructor must be evaluated.

It is okay to add a default constructor to Bar, but after serialization the Foo::Bar::data must point to the Foo::data.

**EDIT: Following is a non-working implementation of my attempt**

This is my attempt based on the hints from @Matthieu. The problem is that when I deserialize Foo, I get no elements in Foo::data and Foo::elements.

```
struct Foo {
    struct Bar {
        std::vector<int> * data;

        Bar( ) : data( 0 ) { }
        Bar( std::vector<int> * d ) : data(d) { }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & data;
        }
    };

    std::vector<int> data;
    std::vector<Bar> elements;

    Foo() {
        std::cerr << "Running default constructor" << std::endl;
        data.push_back(1);
        data.push_back(2);
        data.push_back(3);
        data.push_back(4);
        data.push_back(5);
        elements.push_back( Bar( &data ) );
        elements.push_back( Bar( &data ) );
        elements.push_back( Bar( &data ) );
    }

    template<class Archive>
    Foo( Archive & ar ) {
        ar >> data; // is this corrent?
        ar >> elements;
    }

private:
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER();
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        const std::vector<int> * data_ptr = &data;

        // should data be seriliazed as pointer...
        // it is used as a pointer in Bar
        ar << data_ptr;
        ar << elements;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
#if 0
    // serialize
    Foo foo;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(std::cout);
    oar << foo;

#else
    // deserialize
    boost::archive::text_iarchive oar(std::cin);
    Foo foo(oar);

#endif
    std::cerr << foo.data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << foo.elements.size() << std::endl;

    std::cerr << (&foo.data) << std::endl;
    for( const auto& a : foo.data )
        std::cerr << a << " ";
    std::cerr << std::endl;

    for( const auto& a : foo.elements)
        std::cerr << a.data << " ";
    std::cerr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a section in the documentation that describes how to (de)serialize classes with non-default constructors.  See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors).

Basically, you must implement two functions called `save_construct_data` and `load_construct_data` in the namespace `boost::serialization` to write out and read in the data used to construct instances of your class.  You can then call a non-default constructor of `Foo` from the `load_construct_data` function with the parameters necessary to reconstruct a `Foo` object.

---

Here is a working example based on your updated code:

Note that I've used `shared_ptr`'s to clarify that the `data` member serialized by Foo and Bar are referencing the same thing.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct Foo {
    struct Bar {
        boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > data; // Must point to Foo::data

        Bar( boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > d ) : data(d) { }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
          // ** note that this is empty **
        }
    };

    boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > data;
    std::vector<Bar> elements;

    Foo() : data( new std::vector<int>() ) {
        std::cerr << "Running default constructor" << std::endl;
        data->push_back(1);
        data->push_back(2);
        data->push_back(3);
        data->push_back(4);
        data->push_back(5);
        elements.push_back( Bar( data ) );
        elements.push_back( Bar( data ) );
        elements.push_back( Bar( data ) );
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
      // ** note that this is empty **
    }

    Foo(
      boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > const & data_,
      std::vector<Bar> const & elements_ ) : data( data_ ), elements( elements_ )
    {
        std::cout << "cheap construction" << std::endl;
    }
};

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
inline void save_construct_data(
    Archive & ar, const Foo * foo, const unsigned int file_version
){
    ar << foo->data << foo->elements;
}

template<class Archive>
inline void load_construct_data(
    Archive & ar, Foo * foo, const unsigned int file_version
){
    boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > data;
    std::vector<Foo::Bar> elements;

    ar >> data >> elements;

    ::new(foo)Foo(data, elements);
}

template<class Archive>
inline void save_construct_data(
    Archive & ar, const Foo::Bar * bar, const unsigned int file_version
){
    ar << bar->data;
}

template<class Archive>
inline void load_construct_data(
    Archive & ar, Foo::Bar * bar, const unsigned int file_version
){
    boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > data;

    ar >> data;

    ::new(bar)Foo::Bar(data);
}

}}

int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss;

  {
    boost::scoped_ptr< Foo > foo( new Foo() );

    std::cout << "size before serialization is: " << foo->data->size() << std::endl;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << foo;
  }

  {
    boost::scoped_ptr< Foo > foo;

    boost::archive::text_iarchive is(ss);
    is >> foo;

    std::cout << "size after deserialization is: " << foo->data->size() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. But how would you write the load overload? Foo's default constructor must not be invoked.

Comment: @Allan: you will need to add a constructor specific for deserialization. For example a constructor that takes a boost archive in argument.

Comment: @Matthieu Ahh.. as simple as this, thanks. What about Foo::data, should I serialize it as a pointer, and then do a swap when deserializing?

Comment: @Allan: I think Boost may handle this automatically, otherwise it really depends whether `Bar` should be serializable independently or not. If not, then serializing the pointer is rather pointless.

Comment: @Andrew Durward: Sorry, I still do not get this. How do you intend to actually create a new Foo object using the cheep constructor? The only way I can see (using you suggested solution) is to create a Foo object using the Foo(vector, vector) constructor and then override it using the archive stream. This does not seem like the best solution to me.

Comment: @Allan:  Your updated code doesn't include implementations of `save_construct_data` and `load_construct_data`.  You must provide those _and_ a non-default constructor that can be called from `load_construct_data`.  The non-default constructor can take whatever parameters you choose -- I used vectors while Matthieu suggested the archive itself -- either one is fine).

Comment: @Andrew Durward: To avoid too much refactoring of existing code, I would very much like not Foo as a pointer, and I would like to not make Foo::Bar::data a shared pointer, but keep this as a raw pointer.

Comment: @Allan: I'm sorry I couldn't be of any help.  Have a look at the [documentation section on pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#pointeroperators) for why a raw pointer to a serialized _object_ could be dangerous (hence my reason for using `shared_ptr`'s).  Perhaps somebody else can suggest another way around the problem.

Comment: I have rephrased what I would like to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589658/construct-object-from-boost-serialization-archive