# public empty constructors needed by serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am chasing a rabbit down the hole, by trying to figure out the following:

1. I do not want empty public constructors (they can, and will create issues)
2. Two template classes must remain ignorant of each-other, else I will have template parameter cyclic problems
3. A third class apparently needs access to both previous classes, as it is the one that is being (de)serialized

A minified example is shown below:

```
template <class s_trait>
class state
{
public:
    state(s_trait);
private:
    state() = default;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename archive>
    void serialize(archive &, const unsigned int);
};

template <class a_trait>
class action
{
public:
    action(a_trait);
private:
    action() = default;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename archive>
    void serialize(archive &, const unsigned int);
};

template <class state_type, class action_type>
class policy
{
public:
     /// ... some public methods
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    std::unordered_map<state_class,
                       std::unordered_map<action_class,
                                          double>> __policies__;
    template <typename archive>
    void serialize(archive &, const unsigned int);
};
```

The above skeleton (without the boring details) has the following design issues:

- class `state` cannot be aware of action, if action is to be aware of state
- class `action` cannot be aware of `state` and vice versa
- class `policy` templates the `state` and `action` on purpose

However, compiling an app using those classes creates issues arising from std::pair, which seem to stem from boost::serialization::access, which in turn appear to be from the fact that class `policy` needs access to the default empty constructors when calling `serialize`:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair() [with _T1 = const relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _T2 = std::unordered_map<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, relearn::hasher<relearn::action<mu
mbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double> > >]’:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:132:9:   required from ‘static void boost::serialization::access::construct(T*) [with T = std::pair<const relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::unordered_map<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, rel
earn::hasher<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double> > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:93:22:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_construct_data(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive; T = std::pair<const relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::unordered_map<relearn::act
ion<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, relearn::hasher<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::b
asic_string<char> > >, double> > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:158:28:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive; T = std::pair<const relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::unordered_map<relearn
::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, relearn::hasher<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx
11::basic_string<char> > >, double> > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/detail/stack_constructor.hpp:54:54:   required from ‘boost::serialization::detail::stack_construct<Archive, T>::stack_construct(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive; T = std::pair<const relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >
 >, std::unordered_map<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, relearn::hasher<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::act
ion<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double> > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp:45:55:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::stl::archive_input_unordered_map<Archive, Container>::operator()(Archive&, Container&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive; Container = std::unordered_map<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::
__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::unordered_map<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, relearn::hasher<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator
<std::pair<const relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double> > >, relearn::hasher<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::state<mu
mbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::unordered_map<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double, relearn::hasher<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >
 >, std::allocator<std::pair<const relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, double> > > > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/unordered_collections_load_imp.hpp:66:14:   [ skipping 24 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:618:18:   required from ‘void boost::archive::load(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive; T = relearn::policy<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >
 > >]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:66:22:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = relearn::policy<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >
 >; Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp:76:7:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = relearn::policy<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; 
Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:62:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<Archive, Elem, Tr>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = relearn::policy<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>
 > > >; Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive; Elem = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:60:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator>>(T&) [with T = relearn::policy<relearn::state<mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, relearn::action<mumbler::action<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > 
> >; Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive]’
/home/alex/codez/mumbler/src/agent.cpp:9:11:   required from here
/home/alex/codez/mumbler/src/relearn/src/relearn.hpp:90:5: error: ‘relearn::state<state_trait, value_type>::state() [with state_trait = mumbler::state<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; value_type = double]’ is private
     state() = default;
```

As far as I can see, I have two options:

1. leave a public empty default constructor
2. forward-declare class policy, then befriend it - however this creates the issue that the classes befriending it need be aware of its template parameters, thus they need to be aware of each-other (state-action) which is what I would like to avoid.

Is there some other way to go around this without exposing public empty constructors?

## edit

This is not a duplicate, I know how to (de)serialize, the question is about *hiding* the default constructor for only the (de)serializer to have access to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boost serialization with pointers and non-default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584296/boost-serialization-with-pointers-and-non-default-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your default constructors `protected`, then make a derived class from each that has a public constructor but hide those derived classes from the outside entirely (put them in a `detail` header file that nobody else includes).  Then your `policy` class can use the derived classes internally, for serialization and storage, but only expose them as (sliced) base class objects.

Comment: this is a lovely idea! Not very simple but I will definitely try it! Thank you very much!